# How to clone a child component on click of parent component using events

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a requirement in which i need to create another child component on click of button that is present in the parent component. If I clicked Add criteria button child component should be created.

Please let me know how can I do with help of events.

Parent component code is:

```
<li class="group">
    <div class="slds-p-bottom_medium">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="slds-float_right">
                <div class="slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open">
                  <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border-filled" aria-haspopup="true" title="Show More">
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Show More</span>
                  </button>
                  <div class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_left">
                    <ul class="slds-dropdown__list" role="menu">
                      <li class="slds-dropdown__item" role="presentation">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">
                          <span class="slds-truncate" title="Add Criteria">Add Criteria</span>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="slds-dropdown__item" role="presentation">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">
                          <span class="slds-truncate" title="Add Group">Add Group</span>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="slds-dropdown__item" role="presentation">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">
                          <span class="slds-truncate" title="Delete">Delete</span>
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <c:CPGFilterCriteriaList/>
</li>
```

Child Component:

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-m-top_x-small">
                 <div class="slds-m-right_x-small">
                    <span  class="slds-text-align_center">
                     <ui:outputText value="{!v.seqNo}" /> 
                    </span>
                </div>
               <div class="slds-m-right_x-small">   
                    <lightning:select name="operatorName"  label="" aura:id="OpratorAndOr" value="{!v.selectedAndOrOperator}">
                                <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstOfAndOrOperators}" var="item" >
                                    <option text="{!item.value}" value="{!item.label}" selected="{!item.selected}"  />
                                </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:select>
                </div> 
                <div class="slds-m-right_x-small">
                <lightning:select name="columnName"  label="" aura:id="columnName" value="{!v.selectedColumnName}">
                                <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstOfColumnNames}" var="item1" >
                                    <option text="{!item1.value}" value="{!item1.label}" selected="{!item1.selected}"  />
                                </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:select>
                </div>
                 <div class="slds-m-right_x-small">
                <lightning:select name="Operators"  label="" aura:id="Operators" value="{!v.selectedOperator}">
                                <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstOfOperators}" var="item2" >
                                    <option text="{!item2.value}" value="{!item2.label}" selected="{!item2.selected}"  />
                                </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:select>
                </div> 

                 <div class="slds-m-right_x-small">
                    <ui:inputText aura:id="inpText" placeholder="Text" value=""
                                  class="slds-input" required="true"/>
                </div>
                <button class='slds-button slds-button--icon-border' type='button'> 
                               <!--  <span class='slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-close'></span> -->
                               <lightning:icon iconName="utility:close" variant="close" size="xx-small"/>
                                <span class='slds-assistive-text'>close</span>
                </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a component you should use

```
$A.createComponent(String type, Object attributes, function callback)
```

As described here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm

For the inter-components communication, you should consider component events

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/08/depth-look-lightning-component-events.html